# Datatypes and number representaton

Tags: programming-languages

*I'm a freshman in computer science and I have a question that has been bugging me after my programming and electronics classes were over.*

**My question** is that in an integer datatype (assume **short** datatype in Java, where the range is from -32768 to +32767.) I understand (based on what has been taught) that this is because the leftmost bit MSB is reserved for sign. *However, how does the representation for negative numbers work then? Doesn't it need an extra 1 on the left side?*

Another follow up: isn't sign magnitude an inefficient and usually unused method to perform arithmetic? How then is the output perfect and fast?

- **(please do correct me if I'm wrong, I'd love to grasp every bit of this correctly)** *

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10958/755

Comment: Just as a comment, sign-magnitude is considered inefficient for integer arithmetic today, but the idea lives on in floating point.

Comment: @greybeard There sure is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: "How then is the output perfect and fast?": what do you mean ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust I meant the computation speed and accuracy in result

Answer (score 2):

Let us do 8-bit numbers, it's less writing.

**The left-most bit is *not* the sign.** It contributes $-128$ to the value. More precisely, here are the values of the bits, where bit 0 is the right-most one and bit 8 is the left-most one:

| Bit | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | $2^0 = 1$ |
| 1 | $2^1 = 2$ |
| 2 | $2^2 = 4$ |
| 3 | $2^3 = 8$ |
| 4 | $2^4 = 16$ |
| 5 | $2^5 = 32$ |
| 6 | $2^6 = 64$ |
| 7 | $2^7 = 128$ |

Bit 8 contibutes a negative value. For example `11010000` represents the number $-128 + 64 + 16 = -48$. What represents $-1$? Because
$$-128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = -1$$
the number $-1$ is represented by `11111111`.

Is it clear now?

Comment: So that means the value of what I assumed to be the sign bit is.also accounted for?              
 Should'nt 11010000 be 2^4+2^6+2^7 (since the powers of two start from zero on the right)?

Comment: You're right, thanks, I had an [Obi-Wan error](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Obi-wan%20error). I fixed it, hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

You may notice that the smallest value (negative) has a larger mantissa by one unit than the largest value (positive), and in total there are $2^{16}$ distinct values. These are sure signs that the two's complement representation is used for signed values.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

---

**Addendum:**

The sign/magnitude representation has a big flaw: it has two zeroes.

$$\cdots-3,-2,-1,-0,+0,+1,+2,+3\cdots$$

This creates a quirk in the linearity. While this seems inoccuous, it would make the implementation of arithmetic more complicated and costly.

Comment: No I do know the 1's and 2's complement method of representation. My question was how would you represent powers of 2 that are negative like -64 in sign magnitude when the number of buts available are limited to the respective power of 2. *(Also is there a way to know while seeing a binary value if it is meant to be negative or positive?)*

Comment: @WhizzingPhoton: 1) you can't for the very reason that there are two zeros. 2) as you know about the 2's complement representation, you know that the most significant bit is the sign. If your question is how to tell an unsigned representation from a 2's complements, the answer is clear: you can't.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I got it now